# EF6 Update Foreign Key after insert Data from another Form

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a table's foreign key after I insert record from a different form.

Table **Project**:

```
ProjectID    CommentID
```

Table **Comments**:

```
CommentID   Date    Comment
```

First, I create the `Project` and assign `CommentID` a `NULL` value since there is no comment yet. So far so good.

Then, in some moment, I need to add a comment to my project. I can successfully add comments, but can't assign `CommentID` in related `Project` table.

This is how I'm trying to do (with no success):

```
MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities();

tblComents coment = new tblComments()
        {
            Date = DateComent.Value,
            Comment = TxtComment.Text.Trim()
        };

ctx.tblComments.Add(comment);
var projet = new tblProject { tblComments = comment };
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Like this, I create the comment but the foreign key is never assigned in table `Projects`.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to assign a Collection to a Single Type variable?

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a co**mm**ent - with two **m** (not just one)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the comment to a `new` project that has nothing to do with your database:

```
  tblComents coment = new tblComents()
        {
            Date = DateComent.Value,
            Coment = TxtComent.Text.Trim()
        };
            tblProject project = ctx.tblProject(x=> x.Id == someid); // find the project you want
            if(project != null) project.tblComents.Add(coment);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

You should either get a project from your database (code above) and then add the comment to that project, or add the project to database not the comment(code below):

```
  tblComents coment = new tblComents()
        {
            Date = DateComent.Value,
            Coment = TxtComent.Text.Trim()
        };
            tblProject project = new tblProject();
            ctx.tblProjects.Add(project);

            if(project != null) project.tblComents.Add(coment);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where did Comments come from this line project.Comments.Add(coment);

Comment: Well that line should be ommited! that's actually meant to be `project.tblComents.Add(coment);`That should be added after null check. I corrected the answer